# HIGH in input pin without connect

Tags: arduino

I declare pin 12 as input mode in Arduino UNO. I didn't connect to that pin 12 but if I read state of that pin, the result is always HIGH. I want to avoid that. I made several googling but I don't get cool answer.

Comment: Why would you make it an input if nothing is connected to it? Google "pulldown resistor" and decide if that is cool enough for you.

Comment: Actually, I have plan to connect these port with another output source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you reading that pin? If the intention is to detect an external input (assuming to be a high level signal), put a pull down resistor externally. You only should connect a 10kohm or 20 kohm resistor between arduino input pin and ground.

If you need the pin state to be default high, then you can use internal pull up already present in the ATMEL MCU.

> Properties of Pins Configured as INPUT_PULLUP
>
> There are 20K pullup resistors built into the Atmega chip that can be
>   accessed from software. These built-in pullup resistors are accessed
>   by setting the pinMode() as INPUT_PULLUP. This effectively inverts the
>   behavior of the INPUT mode, where HIGH means the sensor is off, and
>   LOW means the sensor is on.

In case you are pulling the input line ground, then do not enable the internal pullup. Either you should have pull up or pull down in the input line. Not both .

Refer to [this](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/logic/pull-up-resistor.html) for good description

---

Here is sample circuit for pull down.
[image]
 In the code, you onle have to configure it as input. That is all. Do not enable internal pull up.

```
pinMode(inPin, INPUT); // sets the digital pin 7 as input }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a pull-down resistor on it.

Floating (unconnected) inputs can move any way they want. The steady state (if it ever gets to a steady state) depends on the chip architecture, the PCB layout or other signals around it.

However it is more worrying that you care about the state of something you have not connected.

---

I just saw your comment about connecting it to another output source.

This means you have a non-problem: a problem that not really exists.
Connect it and it should all work.

Comment: I'm newcomer for arduino and electronic field. If you are ok, could you please show me just simple code for pull down resistor.

Comment: A pull down resistor isn't code. It's hardware. It's a real resistor. See Umar's answer.